Finding direction of reaction using equillibrium constant
One of the primary uses of equilibrium constant is to compare it with reaction quotient and based on the inequality/equality obtained decide the direction. I have learned that attainment of equillibrium is solely based on the individual components reaching the equilibrium concentration, but there are many ways to reach a number, ie the equilibrium constant (say 3), can be reached by (6x9)/27, or (9x6)/27, so is it wrong ?



What is wrong, exactly?

Say A+B gives AB, if equilibrium constant is 3, then this 3 can be obtained if concentration of AB is 30, A is 5 and B is 2, or if AB is 60 A is 4 and B is 5, well if the equilibrium concentrations of A is 100, B is 113 and AB is 33900, then it dosen't tell us properly if equilibrium is reached...  i think this has flaws

33900/(113100) = 3, so is 60/(45) well both concentrations hint at equilibrium, isn't this a flaw ? so flatly saying that comparing the reaction quotient and equilibrium constant helps in deciding the direction of the reaction is wrong ?

We only have fixed values for equiibrium concentrations, don't we ?

sigh only proportion is fixed.

but how are they in proportion ? [AB:A:B] #1-30:5:2, #2-60:4:5, #3-33900:100:113

proportion between what's over and below the fractional dash.

The equilibrium is attained when your Qc equals Kc. Indeed, Qc= Kc can be obtained for many different concentrations of A, B and AB that you mention.

oh, i was completely unaware of that, wow ! thanks. so depending on the distance between the equilibrium concentration and the current concentration, the shortest distance (low diff.) equilibrium concentration is choosen ?

@Mithoron, well that should be in proportion, for equilibrium constant, my problem is with variation in active masses of individual reactants and yet somehow reaching the equilibrium constant, sorry i am not good at describing stuff

hey so if equilibrium constant is 3, AB:A:B = 20:4:5, or 20:5:4, well A can have 4 or 5 and B can have 4 or 5, so here, or in general put x(y):x:y or x(y):y:x, these are possible but, well they don't include this in textbooks, why though ? this seems important ...

If $\dfrac{x.y}{z}= 3$, it is trivially obvious  that many combinations of all three variables can fit the equation. In fact you  can deliberately choose nonzero values of two of them.

yes, so either the statement in my book is wrong or as Nightwing said, multiple equilibrium concentrations are possible, it is not mentioned in my book though, i wonder why ... [idc]

For the reaction
$$\ce{A + B <=> AB},$$
the equilibrium constant $K_c$ and initial concentrations $c_\ce{A}$, $c_\ce{B}$, $c_\ce{AB}$ with $Q=\frac{c_\ce{AB}}{c_\ce{A}\cdot c_\ce{B}}$,
the equilibrium concentrations are $c_\ce{A}-x$,
$c_\ce{B}-x$,
$c_\ce{AB}+x$,
fitting the equation
$$\frac{c_\ce{AB}+x}{( c_\ce{A}-x)(c_\ce{B}-x)}=K_c$$

The equilibrium will be approached by the forward net reaction if $Q \lt K$ and $x \gt 0$.

The equilibrium will be approached by the backward net  reaction if $Q \gt K$ and $x \lt 0$.



what you say is related, but not the answer you have shown the use of equilibrium constant in deciding the direction of the reaction..., i was completely forgetful of the fact that it is all about maintaining the ratio, whatever concentration we may have if it creates the value of equilibrium constant then it an accepted set of value for equilibrium concentrations.

It does not create the value of the constant. The constant is given.

yea... it 'creates' the same given constant value, sorry my choice of words is not good...

I do not see how this is not the answer. It is the equivalent to what you were searching for. There is no point of statical "creation" of K value. The reaction is shifting and Q is sliding toward K.

It sounds like you're trying to identify a variable that explains some difference between the multiple numerical examples you brought up. There is in fact a difference, but it does not lie in the equilibrium constant in terms of concentrations $K_C$ but rather in the equilibrium constant in terms of molar fractions $K_X$.
Both equilibrium constants are related this way:
$$K_C=K_X\;C^{\Delta n}$$
When you're bringing up these numerical examples that satisfy the equation:
$$K_C=\frac{C_{C_1}}{C_{A_1}\;C_{B_1}}=\frac{C_{C_2}}{C_{A_2}\;C_{B_2}}=\;...$$
$K_C$ remains constant, but not necessarily $K_X$, since the law of mass action only imposes such restriction on the former but not necessarily the latter.
Since we're dealing with the following reaction:
$$\ce{A +B<=>C}$$
$$\Delta n=-1\implies \boxed{K_C=\frac{K_X}{C}}$$
Where C is the total equilibrium concentration.
Using your own examples:
$\space$
$C_{A_1}=\pu{5M}\implies X_{A_1}=\frac{5}{37}$
$C_{B_1}=\pu{2M}\implies X_{B_1}=\frac{2}{37}\implies K_{X_1}=111$
$C_{C_1}=\pu{30M}\implies X_{C_1}=\frac{30}{37}$
$C_1=\pu{37M}$
$\space$
$C_{A_2}=\pu{4M}\implies X_{A_2}=\frac{4}{69}$
$C_{B_2}=\pu{5M}\implies X_{B_2}=\frac{5}{69}\implies K_{X_2}=207$
$C_{C_2}=\pu{60M}\implies X_{C_2}=\frac{60}{69}$
$C_2=\pu{69M}$
In other words, an equilibrium shift forces concentrations of individual species to satisfy the value of $K_C$, but do not necessarily do so for molar fractions and $K_X$.
This means that $K_C$ is a "true" equilibrium constant in the sense that it remains a fixed value (at constant temperature), but $K_X$ is a "pseudo" equilibrium constant because it usually changes even at constant temperature.
Another way to think about it is that the ratio of concentrations between products and reactants is conserved, but the ratio of their compositions usually isn't.
Note that for reactions where $\Delta n=0$, both constants are equal to each other:
$$K_C=K_X$$
In this particular case, both concentration and composition ratios are conserved, whereas in your numerical examples it isn't since $\Delta n\neq0$.

Equilibrium concentration depends on the initial concentration. Depending on initial concentration there can be any set of equilibrium concentrations but they should always make the equilibrium constant.

Is this an answer to your own question or a comment? If a comment instead edit your original question, or submit the comment under the answer or other comment to which you are replying.

It is the answer ...

Ok, I see that you posted first. In any case, my reaction is that many similar questions have been asked on this site and that the answer lacks detail. Your question, if generalized as "are equilibrium solutions unique?" is a good one. I'm not sure that has been asked. It would be a good idea to elaborate on your answer. As you can see from the other answers which include details explaining the concepts more fully.
